# How to configure JDBCAppender programmatically

Tags: log4j

What are the steps involved for configuring a `JDBCAppender` using Java?

I would like to give the appender JDBC parameters and let it build the log table and start logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following:

```
package org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.examples.test;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCLogType;
import org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.examples.MyColumnHandler;
import org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.examples.MyIDHandler;

// Here is a code example to configure the JDBCAppender without a configuration-file using the JDBCIDHandler and JDBCColumnHandler :

public class SourceConfigOracleTest {
// Create a category instance for this class
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4JTest.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
// A JDBCIDHandler
MyIDHandler idhandler = new MyIDHandler();

// A JDBCColumnHandler
MyColumnHandler colHandler = new MyColumnHandler();

// Ensure to have all necessary drivers installed !
try {
  Driver d = (Driver) (Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance());
  DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

// Set the priority which messages have to be logged
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

// Create a new instance of JDBCAppender
JDBCAppender ja = new JDBCAppender();

// Set options with method setOption()
ja.setConnector("org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.examples.OracleConnectionHandler");
ja.setUrl(
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"
    + "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 62.52.100.41)(PORT = 1521)))"
    + "(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = oracle8i)))");
ja.setUsername("danko");
ja.setPassword("danko");

ja.setTable("logtest");

ja.setColumn("id", JDBCLogType.ID, idhandler, "INTEGER", Types.INTEGER);
ja.setColumn("prio", JDBCLogType.PRIO, "", "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);
ja.setColumn("cat", JDBCLogType.CAT, "", "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);
ja.setColumn("msg", JDBCLogType.MSG, "", "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);
ja.setColumn("info", JDBCLogType.DYNAMIC, colHandler, "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);
ja.setColumn("addon", JDBCLogType.EMPTY, "", "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);
ja.setColumn("the_timestamp", JDBCLogType.TIMESTAMP, "", "TIMESTAMP", Types.TIMESTAMP);
ja.setColumn("created_by", JDBCLogType.STATIC, "ME", "VARCHAR", Types.VARCHAR);

// other options
//ja.setBuffer("1");
//ja.setCommit("Y");

// Add the appender to a category
logger.addAppender(ja);

// These messages with Priority >= setted priority will be logged to the database.
logger.debug("debug");
logger.info("info");
logger.error("error");
logger.fatal("fatal");

// not required
logger.removeAppender(ja);
}
}
```